How to receive real-time calorie changes with HealthKit
I am creating a running app that displays distance traveled and calories burned in real time.
Distance is received in real time, but calorie changes are not received or are displayed only after turning on and re-entering the health app.
observeQuery = HKObserverQuery(queryDescriptors: [distanceDescriptor, activeEnergyDescriptor])
        { query, updatedSampleTypes, completionHandler, error in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(#function + " HKObserverQuery " + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            // 속성지정
            
            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: self.startDate, end: Date())
            
            if let types = updatedSampleTypes {
                
                let descriptors = types.map { type in
                    HKQueryDescriptor(sampleType: type, predicate: predicate)
                }
                
                let anchorQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(queryDescriptors: descriptors,
                                                        anchor: self.anchor,
                                                        limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit)
                { anchorQuery, samples, deleted, newAnchor, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        debugPrint(#function + " HKAnchoredObjectQuery " + error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    
                        self.anchor = newAnchor
                        
                        // 가장 최근에 추가된 데이터 확인
                        guard let samples = samples,
                              let sample = samples.last,
                              let sampleQuantity = sample as? HKQuantitySample
                        else {  return }
            
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if sampleQuantity.sampleType == activeEnergyType {
                                self.calorie += sampleQuantity.quantity.doubleValue(for: .kilocalorie())
                            }
                            if sampleQuantity.sampleType == distanceType {
                                self.distance += sampleQuantity.quantity.doubleValue(for: .meter())
                            }
                            
                            self.pace = WorkoutService.calcPace(second: self.seconds, meter: self.distance)
                        }
                        
                        completionHandler()
                    
                }
                self.healthStore.execute(anchorQuery)
            }
        }

How can I receive real-time calorie changes from HealthKit?
